# where on LINQ with DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

```
var results = from myRow in dsPac.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("Package_Name").Equals(lblPackageName.Text)
              select myRow;
```

The `dsPac` contains

[image]

I want to select data corresponding to `Package1712200466` ie

[image]

When I bind to a GridView I get the following error

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property
with the name 'Holiday_ID'.
```

Comment: does it throw any exception?

Comment: yes have edited my question

Comment: There are two columns as shown in the previous picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past when I have data rows that I wish to bind into a GridView, I create an object to do so.  In this case, you could probably use your Linq query to create an anonymous object that will do the trick.

```
 var results = from myRow in dsPac.AsEnumerable()
               where myRow.Field<string>("Package_Name").Equals(lblPackageName.Text)
               select new { Holiday_ID = myRow["Holiday_ID"],
                            Holiday_Description = myRow["Holiday_Description"],
                            Holiday_Date = myRow["Holiday_Date"] };
```

I don't believe biding to the row directly will work - see the exception text.  Row columns are accessed via an Item[] indexer, so you would need to write a WPF converter to achieve the same effect. In all, a waste of time because the Linq query will work.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use [AsDataView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908061.aspx) to convert the row collection back to a DataView which the GridView will be able to bind to.

```
var results = (from myRow in dsPac.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("Package_Name").Equals(lblPackageName.Text)
              select myRow).AsDataView();
```

Comment: @mayer: You could also use `CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, for ur answer.Actually I was also doing some mistake.CopyToDataTable helped me.It solved my problem.